# Need to get files based on name and age

Tags: c#, getfiles

I'm looking for a way to specifically GetFiles that have a specific name AND that have been created within a certain time limit, however I can't figure out how to use both criteria in the same statement, or to find another method to accomplish this.

Here's my code so far:

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);

FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles("ArchiveDeleteLog*" , SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```

Comment: use linq.  `files.Where(x=>x.Name .... &&  x.CreationTime ...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `Where` clause to your `GetFiles` call to filter on files that were created within a specific timeframe:

```
// Adjust these to the date range you are interested in
DateTime startDate = DateTime.MinValue;
DateTime endDate = DateTime.MaxValue;

List<FileInfo> files = dir.GetFiles("ArchiveDeleteLog*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
    .Where(fileInfo =>
        fileInfo.CreationTime >= startDate &&
        fileInfo.CreationTime <= endDate)
    .ToList();
```